# IText 7 not displaying malayalam font correctly

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, fonts, itext

I am using iText7 to add text to a PDF, I am using the language Malayalam, but after saving the PDF the Malayalam text doesn't look normal.

This is what I am getting.

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

This is the code that I used to set up the font.

```
  FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont("malayalam3.ttf");
  PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
  Paragraph namePara = new Paragraph("സുബ്രഹ്മണ്യന്‍");
  namePara.SetFontSize(14);
  namePara.SetFixedPosition(1, 218, NAME_BASE - i * OFFSET, 600).SetFont(font);
```

This is the font that I am using https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gayathri?preview.text=%E0%B4%B8%E0%B5%81%E0%B4%AC%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%B0%E0%B4%B9%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%AE%E0%B4%A3%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%A8%E0%B5%8D%E2%80%8D&preview.text_type=custom&subset=malayalam

Can someone help.

Comment: Do you use the itext 7 pdfCalligraph add-on?

Comment: No, I believe it is a paid addon, right?

Comment: as per the [product page](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfcalligraph), you do require pdfCalligraph for Malayalam rendering